# Get values from a bash output

Tags: arrays, bash, cut

**UPDATE: this was answered much more simply, and turned out not to need grep at all.  Wow, is my face red!**

I’m pretty new to bash programming, so there’s probably an easy answer for this, but while my Googling has turned up lots of bash grep examples and lots of bash array examples, it hasn’t turned up anything I can figure out how to adapt to what I’m trying to do.

The basic idea is that I want to pull one bit out of each line of another program’s output, and put those into an array.  Suppose this is the output:

```
_ filename1 2015-11-06
. filename2 2015-11-04
X filename3 2015-11-01
_ filename4 2015-10-22
```

Everything there is space-separated, not tab-separated.

What I want to do is get an array in bash that contains *just* the filenames, and nothing else.  So the result of running it against the example woudl be a four-item array.  I’ve managed to create arrays that contains all of the space-separated pieces in sequence (thus 12 items), and plenty of empty arrays, but can’t figure out how to get just the filenames.

I’m on an older version of bash that isn’t mine to upgrade (3.2.53(1)-release), so `readarray` is not available.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version uses regexp and deals with spaces in filename:

```
arr = (command | $(sed -s "s/^.\s\(.\+\)\s[0-9\-]\+\$/\1/"))
```

Example:

```
a="_ filename1 2015-11-06                                   
. filename2 2015-11-04
X filename3 2015-11-01
_ filen a m e4 2015-10-22"

echo "$(echo $a | sed -s "s/^.\s\(.\+\)\s[0-9\-]\+\$/\1/")"
```

Outputs:

```
filename1
filename2
filename3
filen a m e4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cut` to grab the 2nd field and put it into an array:

```
arr=($(command | cut -d ' ' -f 2))
```

Another pure BASH option is to use [**process substitution**](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
arr=()
while read -r _ fn _; do
   arr+=("$fn")
done < <(command)
```

---

**EDIT:** To deal with filenames with spaces use:

```
arr=()
while read -r fn ; do
   fn="${fn#* }"
   arr+=("${fn% *}")
done < <(command)
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY the right answer.  Thank you!  I’ll update the question accordingly.

Comment: These options are both only viable if the filenames *cannot* contain spaces. If they can then a more careful parsing needs work.

Comment: Good point, Etan.  In this case, I’m about 99.99% sure the filenames will never contain spaces, but I guess I can’t be certain about the future.  Do you have a more robust suggestion that would handle spaces in fileenames?  I’d love to learn from it!

Comment: It depends on the file format; you either need to use a character that cannot appear in a file name (or really, any other field) as the field delimiter, or you need to be able to guarantee that there are a fixed number of fields following the file name. Otherwise, it's simply ambiguous which spaces are part of the file name and which separate the file name from the next field.

Comment: I've added an updated command to deal with filenames with spaces (assuming we're discarding first and last field from command's output).

Comment: @EricA.Meyer: May I know the reason of un-accepting the answer? Consider these points: 1) You never had requirement of filenames with spaces 2) I still went ahead and provided you a working version to deal with  filenames with spaces. 3) Your chosen answer assumes first field to be a single character which I don't.

Comment: @anubhava: I’d really like to select both answers, since both dealt with the scenario pretty well.  Since I can only pick one, I decided to pick Robert’s because his SO reputation score can use the boost of a selected answer a lot more than yours can.

Comment: Sure it is your prerogative. Bun IMO marked answer should be one that addresses the originally posted problem correctly and it should be independent of poster's reputations.